# Refering to static methods from static variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, static

In python 2.7, I want to create a static variable which stores the result of running a static method of the enclosing class.

I tried the following:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
            return 1
    v = A.foo() # a static variable
print A.v
```

which returns the error:

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

However, referring to another class' static variable works:

```
class B:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
            return 1
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
            return 1
    v = B.foo()

print A.v

>>> 1
```

Any explanations?

EDIT:

The use-case for this scenario is caching the result of foo, and enclose it under A's name space.
Following the answers I understand that A is not yet defined at the execution time, which leads to an error. 
I came up with the following to delay the computation:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
            print 'running foo'
            return 1

    @staticmethod
    def get_v():
            try:
                    return A.v
            except AttributeError:
                    A.v = A.foo()
                    return A.v

print A.get_v()
print A.get_v()

>>> running foo
>>> 1
>>> 1
```

This seems to do the job, but is somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: At that time `A` doesn't even exist, hence the error.

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to do this? Is it just for caching purposes?

Comment: In this example you would want to move `foo()` outside of the class and make it a function, but I suspect you want to do something more complicated.

Comment: Yep, would like to run the function once, and use its return value from multiple instances of A.

Comment: @DanielRoseman edited the question with use-case and possible yet cumbersome solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@classmethod`, and cache the value on the class object.

```
class S(object):
    @classmethod
    def f(klass):
        if not hasattr(klass, '_f'):
            print "Calculating value"
            klass._f = 5

        return klass._f
```

When called twice from different instances:

```
>>> s = S()
>>> s2 = S()
>>> s.f()
Calculating value
5
>>> s2.f()
5
```

The value is shared over all instances of `S`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from wondering why you're doing this: at the time you assign `v` (in the line `v = A.foo()`, `A` has not been defined yet. (The definition of `A` is the *entire* `class` block, so `A` isn't defined until after that block.)

In your second example, `B` is already defined when you say `v = B.foo()`.

EDIT: What puzzles me is the following:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        return 1
    v = foo()
```

Running this code results in

```
    v = foo()
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

Comment: I'd like to cache the return value of foo to run it only once, and share across users of A. Can you offer another way to go?

Comment: Move the function to before `A`'s definition, and within `A`, set `v = foo()`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to keep the function within `A` (as a static method), after `A`'s full definition, write `A.v = A.foo()`.

Comment: That would work, but then foo would be out of A's namespace, which is less convenient for me. I edited the question with another possible option.

Comment: your second option would require that i'll be aware of the first execution of foo.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a (static) method from class A until the class is fully defined (end of block `class`). But you can define a static variable as soon as the class is defined:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        print "running foo"
        return 1
A.v = A.foo()
```

You can then use anywhere

```
print A.v
```

Comment: Do you know why you cannot call `foo` until `A` is fully defined? If `class A: ; foo=lambda:1 ; v=foo()` is allowed, why not `def foo(): return 1` instead of `foo=lambda: 1`?

Comment: @acdr In your example you assign to static variables, assign an *external* function to a variable and call the *external* function through the static variable. It is the same as `def foo(): ; return 1; class A: f = foo; v = f()`. But a *static* method belongs to a class and cannot be executed before the class is fully defined.