# comprehension used in static variable cannot see local function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, static-methods, static-variables

(See final question at EDIT below. The original title was *Why static var in static var is ok but static method not ok in Python?*)

**Original post:** I have a Python question much related to [Refering to static methods from static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863305/refering-to-static-methods-from-static-variables) but not exactly the same. So code where one refers to a static method in
a static variable, e.g.,

```
class A:
   @staticmethod
   def f(a):
      return a*a

   v = f(2)    # A.f(2) does not work either
```

is invalid (and as far as I can tell same holds without @staticmethod as well). Fine. Yet, one can refer to another static variable without any problem:

```
class A:
   i = 2
   v = i * i    # not using A.i here

print(A.v)    # gives 4
```

What is the rationale behind the different treatment of a static variable and a static method here? I am trying from Python 3.6, if it matters.

**EDIT:**

The suggestion by gilch to think of it as a namespace indeed helps. Now I realize that my test case was too simplistic, however. What failed was initializing a list/dictionary for some reason:

```
class A:
   def f(a):  return a*a

   i = f(2)                           #works, indeed
   lst = [2, 3, 4]
   lst2 = [ v*v for v in lst]         #works
   lst3 = [ f(v) for v in lst]        #fails??
   dct =  { f(v) : v for v in lst }   #fails??
```

Of course, the last two lines both work if f is defined outside A. So this may be a question of scope somehow...

Answer (score 4):

Because `staticmethod`s are not callable. They're [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) that return a callable when accessed through a dot (`.`). The class *doesn't exist* until *after* the class body executes. In the meantime, it's a namespace, similar to a module, but with slightly different scoping rules. After the body executes, the namespace is dumped into the class object's `__dict__` and is discarded. So this works.

```
class A:
    def f(a): return a*a
    v = f(2)
    f = staticmethod(f)
```

---

```
>>> A.v
4
>>> A.f(2)
4
```

This also works

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def f(a): return a*a
    v = f.__get__(...)(2)
```

The ellipsis doesn't mean anything. `@staticmethod`'s `__get__()` doesn't use its argument. (It can't be `None`, or it expects another argument. But we have neither a class nor an instance to give it yet.)

---

> What failed was initializing a list/dictionary for some reason:

This is due to the "slightly different scoping rules" that I mentioned earlier.

Comprehensions are compiled like generators -- functions that contain a `yield`. So this would fail for similar reasons:

```
class A:
    def f(a): return a*a
    xs=[2,3,4]
    def comp(it):
        for i in it:
            yield f(i)
    ys=list(comp(xs))
```

Remember that I said the body namespace is discarded. Usually, methods are called after the class body has executed. So methods are compiled to look up names that aren't defined locally in the *global* namespace, instead of the *temporary* class body namespace that probably doesn't exist anymore. It is possible to save this temporary namespace somewhere if you need it, for example,

```
class A:
    def f(a): return a*a
    lst=[2,3,4]
    global ns
    ns = locals()
    lst2=[ns['f'](v) for v in lst]
```

---

```
>>> A.lst2
[4, 9, 16]
```

---

You could also do the comprehensions the old-fashioned way to avoid compiling generators:

```
class A:
    def f(a): return a*a
    lst=[2,3,4]
    lst2=[]
    for v in lst: lst2.append(f(v))
    dct={}
    for v in lst: dct[f(v)] = v
```

---

Or you could wait until after you have a class object to work with (the temporary namespace has been dumped into the object's `__dict__` at this point, so they're available as attrs):

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def f(a):  return a*a
    lst = [2, 3, 4]

A.lst2 = [A.f(v) for v in A.lst]
```

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies a lot. It turns out that thinking of it as a namespace does not help with my original issue, so let me reformulate above at a risk of morphing the question into something else (my test case turns out to be too simplistic).

Comment: Wow, this indeed solves the issue. Thank you! I guess that I will need to change the title though... maybe something like "comprehension in static variable cannot see local function in class?"